# Interacting particle system: how are the particles independent conditionally to the knowledge of their initial positions?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

$\newcommand{\Ex}{\mathbb E}\newcommand{\diff}{\ \mathrm d}$Let

- $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space.
- $B=(B^1, \ldots, B^N)$ independent one-dimensional Brownian motions.
- $X=(X_0^1, \ldots, X_0^N)$ independent real-valued random variables.
- $X$ independent of $B$
- $(P_t, t\ge0)$ a Markov semi-group.
- $V, F:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ smooth functions with compact supports.
- $*$ the convolution operation.

We consider a particle system
$$
X_t^i = X_0^i + \sigma B_t^i - \int_0^t V (X_s^i) \diff s - \int_0^t F * \eta_s (X_s^i) \diff s,
$$
where
$$
\eta_s := \bigg( \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=1}^N \delta_{X_0^j} \bigg ) P_s.
$$

It is menitoned at page $14$ of [this](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07362994.2019.1622426) paper that

> The particles $X^r, 1 \leq r \leq N$, are not independent but they are independent conditionally to the knowledge of the initial random variables $X_0^1, \ldots, X_0^i, \ldots, X_0^N$.

This statement is very intuitive to me because the dependence of $X^r, 1 \leq r \leq N$ comes from the random measure $\eta_s$. After conditioning, this measure becomes "non-random". However, I could not see how to establish the above statement rigorously.

> Could you elaborate on how to obtain above claim?

My definition of [conditional independence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26042/understanding-conditional-independence-of-two-random-variables-given-a-third-one#comment56059_26055) is

> $X,Y$ are conditionally independent given $Z$ if and only if
> $$
> \mathbb P [X \in A, Y \in B | Z] = \mathbb P [X \in A | Z] \cdot \mathbb P [Y \in B | Z]
> \quad \text{a.s.} \quad \forall A,B \in \mathcal B (\mathbb R).
> $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{\nu_x\}_{x \in \mathbb R^n}$ be the regular conditional probability measures on $\Omega$ associated with $X$, and $\mu_X$ the law of $X$ on $\mathbb R^n$.

Denote by $E$ the event
$$\left \{ \nu_X ( \bigcap_i \, \{X^i \in A_i\} ) =
\prod_i \nu_X (X^i \in A_i) \, , \, \forall A_i \in \mathcal B(C[0, T])\right \}.$$

By definition of conditional independence, we need to show that $\mathbb P(E) = 1.$

But for $\mu_X$-a.e. $x$, the $X^i_0$ are deterministic under $\nu_x$, and hence also the process $\eta_s$. As such, for $\mu_X$ a.e. $x$, under $\nu_x$ each $X^i$ is a standard diffusion SDE driven by $B^i$ with non-random coefficients and deterministic initial condition, for which it is known there is a strong solution.

Here independence of $B$ from $X$ guarantees that $B$ is still an independent collection of Brownian motions under each $\nu_x$.

Thus there exist deterministic maps $\Phi_{i, x}$ such that $X^i = \Phi_{i, x} (B_i)$ for all $i$ almost surely under $\nu_x$ for $\mu_X$-a.e. $x$. Independence of the $X^i$ under $\nu_x$ for $\mu_X$-a.e $x$ thus follows from that of the $B_i$.

In other words, denoting by $S$ the set

$$\{ x \in \mathbb R^n \, | \, \nu_x ( \bigcap_i \, \{X^i \in A_i\} ) =
\prod_i \nu_x (X^i \in A_i) \, , \, \forall A_i \in \mathcal B(C[0, T]) \}$$

we have $\mu_X (S) = 1$, and so

$$\mathbb P (E) =  \int_{\mathbb R^n} \mathbf 1_S (X(\omega)) \, d\mathbb P (\omega) = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \mathbf 1_S (x) \, d\mu_X (x) = 1.$$

Thus we conclude conditional independence of the processes $X^i$ as desired.

Comment: In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4664717/if-b-is-a-brownian-motion-independent-of-x-then-b-is-still-a-brownian-mot) question, I can only show that $B$ is still a collection of random variables conditionally independent given $X$ (i.e., under the random measure $\nu_X$). Could you explain how you obtain such independence under *every* $\nu_x$?

Comment: Oh, to be more precise, I mean under $\mu_X$ almost every $\nu_x$. This follows directly from your answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4664244/can-we-characterize-conditional-independence-by-conditional-probability?noredirect=1&lq=1), since (in your notation) $\nu(Z, X^{-1}(A) \cap Y^{-1}(B)) = \nu(Z, X^{-1} (A)) \nu(Z, Y^{-1}(B))$ a.s. if and only if $\nu(z, X^{-1} (A) \cap Y^{-1} (B)) = \nu(z, X^{-1}(A)) \, \nu(z, Y^{-1}(B))$ for $\mu_Z$ a.e. $z$.

Comment: Ah I got the independence under $\nu_x$ for $\mu_X$-a.e. $x \in \mathbb R^n$. Could you explain how $B$ is still a Brownian motion under $\nu_x$ (for $\mu_X$-a.e. $x \in \mathbb R^n$)?

Comment: By definition of conditional probability, we have $\mathbb P(\{B \in A\} \cap \{X \in C\}) = \int_C \nu_x (B \in A) \, d\mu_X$. On the other hand, by independence, $\mathbb P(\{B \in A\} \cap \{X \in C\}) = \mathbb P(B \in A) \mathbb P(X \in C)$. We can write the latter as $\int_C \mathbb P(B \in A) \, d\mu_X$. Since this holds for all Borel $C$, we have $\nu_x (B \in A) = \mathbb P(B \in A)$ for $\mu_X$ a.e. $x$. Ranging $A$ across a countable set of generators for the Borel sigma algebra yields that the law of $B$ under $\nu_x$ is the same as that under $\mathbb P$, for $\mu_X$ a.e. $x$.

Comment: Now I got it. Thank you so much for your dedicated support!

Comment: You’re most welcome! :D